# Slicing a nested tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to slice through a nested tibble?

```
library(tidyverse)

foo <- 
 expand_grid(a = rnorm(100),
             b = runif(100), 
             c = LETTERS[1:10]) %>% 
 group_by(c) %>%
 nest()


slice(foo, 1:4)

   c     data                 
   <chr> <list>               
 1 A     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
 2 B     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
 3 C     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
 4 D     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
 5 E     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
 6 F     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
 7 G     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
 8 H     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
 9 I     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
10 J     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
```

keeps everything. How to retain a specific slice of `foo`?E.g. I expect:

```
slice(foo, 1:6)
        c     data                 
       <chr> <list>               
     1 A     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
     2 B     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
     3 C     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
     4 D     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
     5 E     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
     6 F     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
```

Comment: Maybe `head(foo, 4)` ?

Comment: Tested it. `head` and `tail` work for slicing from the top or the bottom, but not when the range is somewhere in the middle , e.g. as in `slice(foo, 2:4)` for example.

Comment: Why not `foo[2:4, ]` ?

Comment: slice would work, too, if you hadn't used group_by. `foo %>% ungroup() %>% slice(2:4)`

Answer (score 0):

Because the data is grouped, the *slice* is working on each group separately, we need to *ungroup* before slicing:

```
foo %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  slice(2:4)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     c     data                 
#     <chr> <list>               
#   1 B     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
#   2 C     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
#   3 D     <tibble [10,000 x 2]>
```

Or using *base* `[`:

```
foo[2:4, ]
```